# Is it possible to setup user/device management without enrolling in a paid Apple program?

Tags: osx-server, parental-controls, profile-manager

I am using macOS server and a couple of macOS and iOS devices.

I want to start managing settings centrally with Profile Manager (e.g. mail settings, VPN settings, parental controls) but I have gotten stuck. Years ago I used to do this with WorkGroup Manager with earlier versions of OS X Server. Now I am supposed to use Profile Manager for the same. When I tried this many years ago, it did not work so I stopped using it and I have been managing settings locally on each device since. But now it turns out that I cannot locally manage Parental Controls for accounts that are Mobile Accounts, so I need to get to work with Profile Manager again.

1. Can I do that without enrolling in some paid Apple program?

Secondly, how do I start with a simple thing like distributing Mail or VPN settings to macOS and iOS and how do I get Parental Control settings distributed to macOS devices? I have been reading Profile Manager information on Apple support site, but nowhere is there a kind of start guide telling me how to create a payload, how to create a profile (other than creating it, but how do I get useful things into it) etc. Hours spent so far and not a step further.

2. Can someone point me to a useable step-by-step introduction?

Comment: Try [Apple Configurator 2](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator).

Comment: ...and Apple Configurator is free to use

Comment: Looked at that, thanks. I seem to run into a different problem, so I'll ask a separate question.